# non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html - npm http-server

Tags: javascript, html, npm, mime

I´ve got this problem. Is there someone that can point me in the right direction?
I´m using the npm http-server.

This is my html file:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">    
   <meta name="keywords" content="HTML, JavaScript">    
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

   <style>
       .test {
           background-color: black;
       }
   </style>
</head>
   <body>
       <div class="test">
           <img class="duck" src="/assets/anka.png" alt="Fin Anka">
       </div>
       
       <script type="module" src="node_modules/gsap/all.js"></script>
       <script type="module" src="/app.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">    
   <meta name="keywords" content="HTML, JavaScript">    
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

   <style>
       .test {
           background-color: black;
       }
   </style>
</head>
   <body>
       <div class="test">
           <img class="duck" src="/assets/anka.png" alt="Fin Anka">
       </div>
       
       <script type="module" src="node_modules/gsap/all.js"></script>
       <script type="module" src="/app.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

This is my js file:

```
import {gsap} from './node_modules/gsap'

gsap.to(".duck", {duration: 2, x: 300})
```

AND this is the problem:

Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

Comment: if you are attempting to `import` from `gsap/all.js`, your import statement is incorrect. That will result in `index.html` being served in place of your `js` file - and giving you the error you see.. You also don't need a script tag to include the `all.js` if that is what you are attempting to import.

Comment: Ok, thanks!

How should the import look like? I´ve removed the script tag

Comment: You haven't been clear on what you are attempting to import. Are you importing `all.js` from the `gsap` directory?

Comment: This should answer your question: https://greensock.com/docs/v3/Installation#npm-club

Comment: Yes, sorry. I´m trying to import the gsap module. When i import it like in the installation tutorial,{ import {gsap} from 'gsap'}, i get this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "gsap". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Comment: You must ensure the relative reference is correct (that the file can be found relative to the importing file) and if you are not using a bundler, the file extension should be included.